# Data Loader export script to a sharepoint site

Tags: data-loader, dataloader-batch

I created a batch file to automatically export data from Salesforce using dataloader.

Right now the extraction path is in the local drive then I have to manually upload all to our sharepoint site.

```
<entry key="dataAccess.name" value="C:\Users\Name\Sample Folder\Sample File.csv"/>
```

I tried changing the path above to the link but the process throws an error.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a batch script and can schedule it on windows machine.

[Here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/43048) is how you can  map SharePoint to a drive. after that just a scheduled copy command